# I cannot access a Database with SQLite in Android Studio

Tags: java, android, database, sqlite

I'm building a aplication but when i try write data in there, show the error in the log.

Class ActCadContatos.java

```
package com.example.gabrielgomes.agendacontact;

import android.database.SQLException;
import android.database.sqlite.SQLiteDatabase;
import android.os.Bundle;
import android.support.design.widget.FloatingActionButton;
import android.support.design.widget.Snackbar;
import android.support.v7.app.AlertDialog;
import android.support.v7.app.AppCompatActivity;
import android.support.v7.widget.Toolbar;
import android.view.*;
import android.widget.*;

import com.example.gabrielgomes.agendacontact.database.DataBase;
import com.example.gabrielgomes.agendacontact.dominio.RepositorioContato;
import com.example.gabrielgomes.agendacontact.dominio.entidades.Contato;

import java.util.Date;

public class ActCadContatos extends AppCompatActivity {

    private EditText edtNome;
    private EditText edtTelefone;
    private EditText edtEmail;
    private EditText edtEndereco;
    private EditText edtDatasEspeciais;
    private EditText edtGrupos;

    private Spinner spnTipoTelefone;
    private Spinner spnTipoEmail;
    private Spinner spnTipoEndereco;
    private Spinner spnDatasEspeciais;

    //ArrayAdapter for save the options of the Spinner
    private ArrayAdapter<String> adpTipoEmail;
    private ArrayAdapter<String> adpTipoTelefone;
    private ArrayAdapter<String> adpTipoEndereco;
    private ArrayAdapter<String> adpTipoDatasEspeciais;

    //Objects for connection database
    private DataBase dataBase;
    private SQLiteDatabase conn;
    private RepositorioContato repositorioContato;
    private Contato contato;

    @Override
    protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        setContentView(R.layout.activity_act_cad_contatos);
        Toolbar toolbar = (Toolbar) findViewById(R.id.toolbar);
        setSupportActionBar(toolbar);

        FloatingActionButton fab = (FloatingActionButton) findViewById(R.id.fab);
        fab.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
            @Override
            public void onClick(View view) {
                Snackbar.make(view, "Replace with your own action", Snackbar.LENGTH_LONG)
                        .setAction("Action", null).show();
            }
        });

        edtNome = (EditText)findViewById(R.id.edtNome);
        edtTelefone = (EditText)findViewById(R.id.edtTelefone);
        edtEmail = (EditText)findViewById(R.id.edtEmail);
        edtEndereco = (EditText)findViewById(R.id.edtEndereco);
        edtDatasEspeciais = (EditText)findViewById(R.id.edtDatasEspeciais);
        edtGrupos = (EditText)findViewById(R.id.edtGrupos);

        spnTipoTelefone = (Spinner)findViewById(R.id.spnTipoTelefone);
        spnTipoEndereco = (Spinner)findViewById(R.id.spnTipoEndereco);
        spnTipoEmail = (Spinner)findViewById(R.id.spnTipoEmail);
        spnDatasEspeciais = (Spinner)findViewById(R.id.spnDatasEspeciais);

        //Recovering the ArrayAdapter's
        adpTipoEmail = new ArrayAdapter<String>(this, android.R.layout.simple_spinner_item);
        adpTipoEmail.setDropDownViewResource(android.R.layout.simple_spinner_dropdown_item);

        adpTipoEndereco = new ArrayAdapter<String>(this, android.R.layout.simple_spinner_item);
        adpTipoEndereco.setDropDownViewResource(android.R.layout.simple_spinner_dropdown_item);

        adpTipoTelefone = new ArrayAdapter<String>(this, android.R.layout.simple_spinner_item);
        adpTipoTelefone.setDropDownViewResource(android.R.layout.simple_spinner_dropdown_item);

        adpTipoDatasEspeciais = new ArrayAdapter<String>(this, android.R.layout.simple_spinner_item);
        adpTipoDatasEspeciais.setDropDownViewResource(android.R.layout.simple_spinner_dropdown_item);

        //Connect object kind Spinner in a ArrayAdapter
        spnTipoEmail.setAdapter(adpTipoEmail);
        spnTipoEndereco.setAdapter(adpTipoEndereco);
        spnTipoTelefone.setAdapter(adpTipoTelefone);
        spnDatasEspeciais.setAdapter(adpTipoDatasEspeciais);

        //Add option in the ArrayAdapter for put in the Spinner
        adpTipoEmail.add("Pessoal");
        adpTipoEmail.add("Trabalho");
        adpTipoEmail.add("Outros");

        adpTipoTelefone.add("Casa");
        adpTipoTelefone.add("Trabalho");

        adpTipoEndereco.add("Casa");
        adpTipoEndereco.add("Trabalho");
        adpTipoEndereco.add("Outros");

        adpTipoDatasEspeciais.add("Aniversário");
        adpTipoDatasEspeciais.add("Namoro");
        adpTipoDatasEspeciais.add("Casamento");

        //Connection to database
        try {

            //dataBase comes to Class "Database" that create and upgrade the tables
            dataBase = new DataBase(this);
            //conn comes SQLiteDatabase Class it's Android default
            conn = dataBase.getWritableDatabase();
            //repositorioContato is where we sent the datas for input the database
            RepositorioContato repositorioContato = new RepositorioContato(conn);

        } catch (SQLException e){

            AlertDialog.Builder dlg = new AlertDialog.Builder(this);
            dlg.setMessage("Error to connect: " + e.getMessage());
            dlg.setNeutralButton("OK", null);
            dlg.show();

        }

    }

    //Method for create the menu and connect This with menu.xml
    @Override
    public boolean onCreateOptionsMenu(Menu menu) {

        MenuInflater inflater = getMenuInflater();
        inflater.inflate(R.menu.menu_act_cad_contato, menu);

        return super.onCreateOptionsMenu(menu);

    }

    //Method for create the action menu for regitry
    @Override
    public boolean onOptionsItemSelected(MenuItem item) {

        switch (item.getItemId()){

            case R.id.mni_acao1:

                //why?
                if (contato == null){

                    inserir();
                }

                finish();

                break;
            case R.id.mni_acao2:
                break;

        }

        return super.onOptionsItemSelected(item);
    }

    //Method for insert datas of the activity for the database altrought get and setter
    private void inserir(){

        try {

            contato = new Contato();
            contato.setNome(edtNome.getText().toString());
            contato.setTelefone(edtTelefone.getText().toString());
            contato.setTipoTelefone("");
            contato.setEmail(edtEmail.getText().toString());
            contato.setTipoEmail("");
            contato.setEndereco(edtEndereco.getText().toString());
            contato.setTipoEndereco("");
            Date date = new Date();
            contato.setDatasEspeciais(date);
            contato.setTipoDatasEspeciais("");
            contato.setGrupos(edtGrupos.getText().toString());
            repositorioContato.inserir(contato);

        } catch (SQLException e){

            AlertDialog.Builder dlg = new AlertDialog.Builder(this);
            dlg.setMessage("Error to insert the datas: " + e.getMessage());
            dlg.setNeutralButton("OK", null);
            dlg.show();

        }

    }

}
```

Database Class

```
    package com.example.gabrielgomes.agendacontact.database;

    import android.content.Context;
    import android.database.sqlite.*;

    /**
     * Created by Gabriel Gomes on 31/07/2016.
     */

//Class responsable by create Database, SQLiteOpenHelper just be extends
public class DataBase extends SQLiteOpenHelper {

    //Constructor
    public DataBase(Context context){
        //Context, database name, null, version of schema
        super(context, "AGENDA", null, 1);

    }

    //Create table
    @Override
    public void onCreate(SQLiteDatabase db) {

        db.execSQL(ScriptSQL.getCreateContato());

    }

    @Override
    public void onUpgrade(SQLiteDatabase db, int oldVersion, int newVersion) {



    }
}
```

Script Class

```
package com.example.gabrielgomes.agendacontact.database;

/**
 * Created by Gabriel Gomes on 31/07/2016.
 */

//Class for script SQL
public class ScriptSQL {

    //Static method, don't need instace for access it
    public static String getCreateContato(){

        StringBuilder sqlBuilder = new StringBuilder();
        sqlBuilder.append("CREATE TABLE IF NOT EXISTS CONTATO ( ");
        sqlBuilder.append("_id INTEGER NOT NULL ");
        sqlBuilder.append("PRIMARY KEY AUTOINCREMENT, ");
        //sqlBuilder.append("NOME VARCHAR (200), ");
        sqlBuilder.append("TELEFONE VARCHAR (14), ");
        sqlBuilder.append("TIPOTELEFONE VARCHAR (1), ");
        sqlBuilder.append("EMAIL VARCHAR (255), ");
        sqlBuilder.append("TIPOEMAIL VARCHAR (1), ");
        sqlBuilder.append("ENDERECO VARCHAR (255), ");
        sqlBuilder.append("TIPOENDERECO VARCHAR (1), ");
        sqlBuilder.append("DATASESPECIAIS DATE, ");
        sqlBuilder.append("TIPODATASESPECIAIS VARCHAR (1), ");
        sqlBuilder.append("GRUPOS VARCHAR (255) ");
        sqlBuilder.append(");");

        return sqlBuilder.toString();

    }

}
```

Repositorio Class

```
package com.example.gabrielgomes.agendacontact.dominio;

import android.content.ContentValues;
import android.content.Context;
import android.database.Cursor;
import android.database.sqlite.*;
import android.widget.ArrayAdapter;

import com.example.gabrielgomes.agendacontact.R;
import com.example.gabrielgomes.agendacontact.dominio.entidades.Contato;

/**
 * Created by Gabriel Gomes on 31/07/2016.
 */

//Class responsible for realize get the data in the content view, consulting in the database, and return the object Array to fill ListView
public class RepositorioContato {

    private SQLiteDatabase conn;

    //Constructor
    public RepositorioContato(SQLiteDatabase conn){

        this.conn = conn;

    }

    //Method for insert datas of the activity in the database
    public void inserir(Contato contato){

        ContentValues values = new ContentValues();
        values.put("NOME", contato.getNome());
        values.put("TELEFONE", contato.getTelefone());
        values.put("TIPOTELEFONE", contato.getTipoTelefone());
        values.put("EMAIL", contato.getEmail());
        values.put("TIPOEMAIL", contato.getTipoEmail());
        values.put("ENDERECO", contato.getEndereco());
        values.put("TIPOENDERECO", contato.getTipoEndereco());
        values.put("DATASESPECIAIS", contato.getDatasEspeciais().getTime());
        values.put("TIPODATASESPECIAIS", contato.getTipoDatasEspeciais());
        values.put("GRUPOS", contato.getGrupos());
        conn.insertOrThrow("CONTATO", null, values);
    }
    //Atention: atribute bellow is kind date, so it's need the .getTime() method.

    //Test for insert datas
    /*public void testInserirContatos(){

        for (int i=0; i<10; i++){

            //For insert datas in the database
            ContentValues values = new ContentValues();
            values.put("TELEFONE", "5555555");
            //name table, null, values.put
            conn.insertOrThrow("CONTATO", null, values);

        }

    }*/

    //This method make the search and save all datas of the table on the Array
    public ArrayAdapter<String> buscaContatos(Context context){

        ArrayAdapter<String> adpContatos = new ArrayAdapter<String>(context, android.R.layout.simple_list_item_1);

        //Save all resgitry   //.query - Method for consulting: table name,
        Cursor cursor = conn.query("CONTATO", null, null, null, null, null, null);

        //If content of cursor have data more 0, fill ArrayAdapter with cursor data
        if (cursor.getCount() > 0) {

            //Move cursor to first data of the Array
            cursor.moveToFirst();

            //Loop for take all registry if have it
            do {
                //getString catch the index column
                String telefone = cursor.getString(1);
                adpContatos.add(telefone);

            } while (cursor.moveToNext());

        }

        return adpContatos;

    }

}
```

content_act_cad_contato.xml

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<LinearLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    xmlns:app="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res-auto"
    xmlns:tools="http://schemas.android.com/tools"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent"
    android:paddingBottom="@dimen/activity_vertical_margin"
    android:paddingLeft="@dimen/activity_horizontal_margin"
    android:paddingRight="@dimen/activity_horizontal_margin"
    android:paddingTop="@dimen/activity_vertical_margin"
    app:layout_behavior="@string/appbar_scrolling_view_behavior"
    tools:context="com.example.gabrielgomes.agendacontact.ActCadContatos"
    tools:showIn="@layout/activity_act_cad_contatos"
    android:orientation="vertical">

    <LinearLayout
        android:orientation="vertical"
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:id="@+id/lnlCampoNome">

        <TextView
            android:layout_width="wrap_content"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:textAppearance="?android:attr/textAppearanceMedium"
            android:text="@string/lbl_Nome"
            android:id="@+id/textView" />

        <EditText
            android:layout_width="match_parent"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:inputType="textPersonName"
            android:ems="10"
            android:id="@+id/edtNome" />

    </LinearLayout>

    <LinearLayout
        android:orientation="vertical"
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:id="@+id/lnlCampoTelefone">

        <TextView
            android:layout_width="wrap_content"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:textAppearance="?android:attr/textAppearanceMedium"
            android:text="@string/lbl_Telefone"
            android:id="@+id/textView2" />

        <LinearLayout
            android:orientation="horizontal"
            android:layout_width="match_parent"
            android:layout_height="match_parent">

            <EditText
                android:layout_width="wrap_content"
                android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                android:inputType="phone"
                android:ems="10"
                android:id="@+id/edtTelefone" />

            <Spinner
                android:layout_width="150dp"
                android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                android:id="@+id/spnTipoTelefone" />
        </LinearLayout>
    </LinearLayout>

    <LinearLayout
        android:orientation="vertical"
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:id="@+id/lnlCampoEmail">

        <TextView
            android:layout_width="wrap_content"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:textAppearance="?android:attr/textAppearanceMedium"
            android:text="@string/lbl_Email"
            android:id="@+id/textView3" />

        <LinearLayout
            android:orientation="horizontal"
            android:layout_width="match_parent"
            android:layout_height="match_parent" >

            <EditText
                android:layout_width="wrap_content"
                android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                android:ems="10"
                android:id="@+id/edtEmail"
                android:inputType="textEmailAddress" />

            <Spinner
                android:layout_width="150dp"
                android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                android:id="@+id/spnTipoEmail" />
        </LinearLayout>
    </LinearLayout>

    <LinearLayout
        android:orientation="vertical"
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:id="@+id/lnlCampoEndereco">

        <TextView
            android:layout_width="wrap_content"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:textAppearance="?android:attr/textAppearanceMedium"
            android:text="@string/lbl_Endereco"
            android:id="@+id/textView4" />

        <LinearLayout
            android:orientation="horizontal"
            android:layout_width="match_parent"
            android:layout_height="match_parent" >

            <EditText
                android:layout_width="wrap_content"
                android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                android:ems="10"
                android:id="@+id/edtEndereco"
                android:inputType="textPersonName" />

            <Spinner
                android:layout_width="150dp"
                android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                android:id="@+id/spnTipoEndereco" />
        </LinearLayout>
    </LinearLayout>

    <LinearLayout
        android:orientation="vertical"
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:id="@+id/lnlCampoDatasEspeciais">

        <TextView
            android:layout_width="wrap_content"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:textAppearance="?android:attr/textAppearanceMedium"
            android:text="@string/lbl_Datas_Especiais"
            android:id="@+id/textView5" />

        <LinearLayout
            android:orientation="horizontal"
            android:layout_width="match_parent"
            android:layout_height="match_parent" >

            <EditText
                android:layout_width="wrap_content"
                android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                android:ems="10"
                android:id="@+id/edtDatasEspeciais"
                android:inputType="date" />

            <Spinner
                android:layout_width="150dp"
                android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                android:id="@+id/spnDatasEspeciais" />
        </LinearLayout>
    </LinearLayout>

    <LinearLayout
        android:orientation="vertical"
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:id="@+id/lnlGrupo">

        <TextView
            android:layout_width="wrap_content"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:textAppearance="?android:attr/textAppearanceMedium"
            android:text="@string/lbl_Grupos"
            android:id="@+id/textView6" />

        <LinearLayout
            android:orientation="horizontal"
            android:layout_width="match_parent"
            android:layout_height="match_parent" >

            <EditText
                android:layout_width="match_parent"
                android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                android:ems="10"
                android:id="@+id/edtGrupos"
                android:inputType="textPersonName" />

        </LinearLayout>
    </LinearLayout>

</LinearLayout>
```

LOG:

08-06 16:35:22.832 2268-2268/com.example.gabrielgomes.agendacontact E/AndroidRuntime: FATAL EXCEPTION: main
                                                                                      Process: com.example.gabrielgomes.agendacontact, PID: 2268
                                                                                      java.lang.NullPointerException: Attempt to invoke virtual method 'void com.example.gabrielgomes.agendacontact.dominio.RepositorioContato.inserir(com.example.gabrielgomes.agendacontact.dominio.entidades.Contato)' on a null object reference
                                                                                          at com.example.gabrielgomes.agendacontact.ActCadContatos.inserir(ActCadContatos.java:183)
                                                                                          at com.example.gabrielgomes.agendacontact.ActCadContatos.onOptionsItemSelected(ActCadContatos.java:152)
                                                                                          at android.app.Activity.onMenuItemSelected(Activity.java:2885)
                                                                                          at android.support.v4.app.FragmentActivity.onMenuItemSelected(FragmentActivity.java:404)
                                                                                          at android.support.v7.app.AppCompatActivity.onMenuItemSelected(AppCompatActivity.java:179)
                                                                                          at android.support.v7.view.WindowCallbackWrapper.onMenuItemSelected(WindowCallbackWrapper.java:100)
                                                                                          at android.support.v7.view.WindowCallbackWrapper.onMenuItemSelected(WindowCallbackWrapper.java:100)
                                                                                          at android.support.v7.app.ToolbarActionBar$2.onMenuItemClick(ToolbarActionBar.java:69)
                                                                                          at android.support.v7.widget.Toolbar$1.onMenuItemClick(Toolbar.java:169)
                                                                                          at android.support.v7.widget.ActionMenuView$MenuBuilderCallback.onMenuItemSelected(ActionMenuView.java:760)
                                                                                          at android.support.v7.view.menu.MenuBuilder.dispatchMenuItemSelected(MenuBuilder.java:811)
                                                                                          at android.support.v7.view.menu.MenuItemImpl.invoke(MenuItemImpl.java:152)
                                                                                          at android.support.v7.view.menu.MenuBuilder.performItemAction(MenuBuilder.java:958)
                                                                                          at android.support.v7.view.menu.MenuBuilder.performItemAction(MenuBuilder.java:948)
                                                                                          at android.support.v7.view.menu.MenuPopupHelper.onItemClick(MenuPopupHelper.java:191)
                                                                                          at android.widget.AdapterView.performItemClick(AdapterView.java:305)
                                                                                          at android.widget.AbsListView.performItemClick(AbsListView.java:1146)
                                                                                          at android.widget.AbsListView$PerformClick.run(AbsListView.java:3053)
                                                                                          at android.widget.AbsListView$3.run(AbsListView.java:3860)
                                                                                          at android.os.Handler.handleCallback(Handler.java:739)
                                                                                          at android.os.Handler.dispatchMessage(Handler.java:95)
                                                                                          at android.os.Looper.loop(Looper.java:135)
                                                                                          at android.app.ActivityThread.main(ActivityThread.java:5254)
                                                                                          at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Native Method)
                                                                                          at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:372)
                                                                                          at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit$MethodAndArgsCaller.run(ZygoteInit.java:903)
                                                                                          at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit.main(ZygoteInit.java:698)
08-06 16:35:25.308 2268-2268/com.example.gabrielgomes.agendacontact I/Process: Sending signal. PID: 2268 SIG: 9
08-06 16:35:27.992 4214-4239/com.example.gabrielgomes.agendacontact D/OpenGLRenderer: endAllStagingAnimators on 0x7fe895d4a400 (RippleDrawable) with handle 0x7fe895c7f5a0
08-06 16:36:56.285 4214-4222/com.example.gabrielgomes.agendacontact W/art: Suspending all threads took: 7.399ms
08-06 16:38:36.537 4214-4222/com.example.gabrielgomes.agendacontact W/art: Suspending all threads took: 9.017ms
08-06 16:43:31.304 4214-4222/com.example.gabrielgomes.agendacontact W/art: Suspending all threads took: 5.852ms
08-06 16:43:37.818 4214-4222/com.example.gabrielgomes.agendacontact W/art: Suspending all threads took: 8.820ms

Comment: its a null object reference... have a debugger and check whether you are passing right value also check y is your object null..

Comment: You're calling `finish()` in `ActCadContatos` class rightafter calling `inserir()`. Maybe thats causing trouble.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

See below, you have declared

```
RepositorioContato repositorioContato;
```

here:

[image]

Now as we know about concept of "scope". Below you are again creating and initializing (in this scope i.e try block {}) the same reference "repositorioContato"

```
RepositorioContato repositorioContato = new RepositorioContato(conn);
```

here:

[image]

So when you call the

[image]

It will access the top most reference (which will be null, because try block scope will not be accessible here...)

Hope I made clear, if any problem still persistes, feel free to ask :)

Comment: Thank you, so much!